java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Key: data not found in bean: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache using OGNL path [[dat
from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:6060/updateData")
      .log("Received update request: ${body}")
      .setBody(simple("UPDATE my_table SET data = :#${body[data]} WHERE id = :#${body[id]}"))
      .to("sql:update") // Replace with your actual SQL query and dataSource
      .setBody(simple("Data updated at ${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}"))
      .to("direct:notifyServiceB");

// Route to notify Service B using HTTP
from("direct:notifyServiceB")
      .log("Notifying Service B")
      .to("http://localhost:8081/serviceB/notify")
      .log("Notification sent to Service B");

from Service A endpoint when I am trying to hit from postman getting this exception.

Failed to invoke method: [data] on org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache due to: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Key: data not found in bean: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache@8bc328c of type: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache using OGNL path [[data]


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Failed to invoke method: [data] on org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache due to: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Key: data not found in bean: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache@8bc328c of type: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache using OGNL path [[data]]

Hi, I'm getting this while executing my postman request

Please include the output of your log endpoint, where you are printing the ${body}. You would typically expect either a java object with a field called data or a map with a key called data. Looks like you don't have any of these

Issue resolved Thanks everyone
